# Toggling between Speaker and Microphone : Automatic conversion of microphone to speaker and back in continuous loop

Tags: drivers, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

I did go through hdajackretask and alsa project to retask my headphone to microphone.

But what I am wondering if its possible to continuously alternate between microphone and head-phone using script?

Say for few seconds the jack records and then it switches back to speaker and then starts recording again and loop goes on..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Documentation/sound/hd-audio/notes.rst` in the Linux kernel source. You can write to `user_pin_configs` and `reconfig` to trigger reconfiguration, but the driver will reset, so I'm not sure if it's a good way to do that...

Alternatively, you could try to configure the codec to playback and record on the same pin *at the same time* (if this is what you want). But this may need tricking the ALSA driver into thinking that it's really doing playback and recording to/from different pins, and then changing the codec configuration with `hda-verb` without the driver noticing. Not easy, but worth a try.

I'm not sure what you are going to try to do (use the headphone speakers as microphone?), and I don't think I want to test that on my hardware. :-)

Comment: Yes I want to use headphone as speaker alternatively. I dont want to record and play at same time rather do it alternatively.

Comment: Nothing stops you from muting playback and only recording while playback is muted, and then unmuting and stop recording ... might be easier to do than go through the hassle of switching and reinitializing the driver.

Comment: How can record and play from same port without doing jack retasking each time?

Comment: As I said: Start record and playback, see if you can use `hda_verb` to change the codec mux/amp/switch to the same pin widget. Look at `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` for your codec configuration, maybe compare what it does when you use hdajacketask. Read up in the HDA Standard (google) what the verbs do. I'm not going to try this on my hardware, so I can't give you step-by-step instructions (which depend on your codec, anyway).